# Does Microsoft Azure have a REST API to view information about Backup Vaults?

Tags: rest, azure, backup

I'd like to consume information about the Recovery Services that I have setup in Azure. If I go to that section inside the Microsoft Azure Management Portal, I'll see a list of the Backup Vaults that I have created. I'm looking for an API that will let me pull up data about it, such as the one that is presented on the Dashboard:
- Name
- Status
- Location
- Storage used/left
- etc.

So far, I've only been able to find their [Storage Services REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179355.aspx).

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the same thing on the MSDN forums. Apparently, as of this date, there is no API that can be used to pull in that information.

Source: [reply from MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e13790cf-1580-434b-83e5-7b9f952b9295/backup-vaults-information-from-api?forum=windowsazuremanagement)

Comment: Any chance you've found something in the past ~2 years? All I've been able to do is get it to return a useless meta object for a top level vault via the management API.

Comment: Hey @jdc0589
I didn't find anything else that was useful at the time and I'm no longer actively developing those features. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

2016 update: While not documented so far as I can tell, if you do some network sniffing of the various Recovery Services powershell cmdlets you will find that the `management.azure.com` API supports basically everything Azure Powershell supports.

Obviously be careful using anything undocumented though...